# Count the number of the record of this query - a count for distinct pairs before

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my T-SQL query code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    StateProvince, City
FROM
    adventureworks.SalesLT.Address
WHERE 
    CountryRegion LIKE 'Canada' 
    AND StateProvince != 'Quebec'
ORDER BY 
    StateProvince, City
```

I tried to use this, but it did not work out

```
SELECT  
    COUNT (DISTINCT StateProvince, City) OVER (PARTITION BY )
FROM
    adventureworks.SalesLT.Address
WHERE 
    CountryRegion LIKE 'Canada' 
    AND StateProvince != 'Quebec'
ORDER BY 
    StateProvince, City
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results

Answer (score 1):

that is better to use GROUP BY in T-SQL for aggregate functions like COUNT, SUM and so on.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
From adventureworks.SalesLT.Address
WHERE CountryRegion LIKE 'Canada' AND StateProvince != 'Quebec'
GROUP BY City, StateProvince
ORDER BY StateProvince, City
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I tried your code but it still did not work out, unfortunately.

Comment: can you share your error or some sample data?